# NULL checkbox in SSRS report

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SSRS report if I mention `Nullable` tag in `ReportParameter` then it automatically creates a checkbox with text `NULL`. So is there a way to make the checkbox by default checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the default to `=Nothing`, i.e. NULL.

Or even just specify it from the dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just set the parameter default value to 'TRUE'

[image]

This will result in

[image]